# bypandas shape (n,1) to shape (n,)

Tags: python, pandas, reshape

I have a pandas dataframe and I want to convert it from (n,1) to shape (n,). Probably I have to use squeeze but can't figure out, How to. [squeeze documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html)

I also tried `z['0']=z['0'].squeeze()` but it didn't help.
How can I convert?

Comment: Does using `.values` work?

Comment: @Farhang Amaji  : can you elaborate more with an example. what is the expected output and what is the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`z=z.squeeze()` works the best and keeps the result dataframe. of course maybe its because I just had one columns, and didn't check it for more columns.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> s = pd.DataFrame({"col" : range(5)})
>>> s.shape
(5,1)

>>> s.col.to_numpy().shape
(5,)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in `.to_numpy()`:

```py
array = z['0'].to_numpy()
```